How many laptops can one take from US to Dubai?
How many laptops can a traveller (with Indian passport on H1B) from US take to Dubai on a tourist visa?
Will 4-5 laptops cause any issue in terms of customs tax, etc. while entering Dubai or leaving from US?
Can these laptops be in sealed or unsealed boxes?
Edit:
As many have rightly asked about the intent which is of concern when gauging the feasibility of this move - US traveller will get 4 laptops (1 personal, 1 office, and 2 for friends as presents) to Dubai on tourist visa and then give 2 of those new laptops to his friends in Dubai who will all travel in a few days to India. These friends are also Indian citizens who will be in Dubai for a trip on tourist visa. Do not want to engage in anything illegal such as smuggling per se. Just want to know if Dubai authorities are cool with 4 laptops on one person I guess. Thanks.

I don't know if they have special rules in Dubai, but in general you have to argue that they are for personal use. Having them in (sealed) boxes probably makes that harder.

What is your intent?  Are they yours, for your personal use?  Are they new/used?  Are you planning to sell them in Dubai while there on a tourist visa?

Usually, the quantity itself it not an issue. What you intend to do with them (mostly whether you will take them back out of the country again) is much more important. And it’s a lot less likely you will take them back out if you have a lot and many are still factory sealed…

Why would you need 4 or 5 laptops for a visit to Dubai?

Is there also restriction on airlines about number of electronic items (battery)?

Why bring your friends' new laptops with you? If they're not available on the Indian market at all, you could just mail them to your friends, and avoid all the possible hassle with customs (potentially have to pay duties and taxes twice, once on import to UAE and once in India!), theft, airline restrictions, etc.

Legally: As many as you intend to take out.
Practically: As many as you can justify to customs. Most I've done is two unsealed laptops (personal and work), and if requested by customs I would able to turn them on and prove that they're set up for that purpose.
If you are leaving for an onward destination shortly (like India), you may be able to convince customs that you will pay duties on that end. And you should pay duties on that end, lest you risk smuggling charges.

Right now the limit for tax exempt imports by travelers is 3000AED. This is around 800USD right now, so maybe you could import one cheap computer intended as a gift for free?
https://www.dubaicustoms.gov.ae/en/mobile/Pages/faq.aspx
This limit applies to all your belongings that will not leave UAE, incl. any food items, clothing, etc you may intend to gift. I'd bring an invoice of at least the expensive items.

If you don't intend to bring them back out, and you go through the green line, you'd legally be smuggling goods into dubai.
Quoting this law website:

According to Article 142 of the Common Customs Law, smuggling refers to the act or attempting of getting goods into or out of the country in violation of the legislation in force without payment of the customs taxes / duties, either in whole or in part or contrary to the provisions of the UAE laws.


If the smuggled items are subject to high customs taxes, penalty would be fine not less than twice the customs tax payable and not more than 3 times the customs tax or twice the value of the goods, whichever is higher, and / or imprisonment between 1 month to 1 year. For other cases, penalties include a fine not less than double the customs tax payable and not more than the value of the goods and / or imprisonment between 1 month to 1 year.

Further charges may apply to anyone that assists you, and sells these smuggled goods.
I for one wouldn't want to pay 8-10 laptops' worth of fines, and/or spend up to a year in a UAE prison. This would also be part of your criminal record and may affect immigration in the future.

If someone else is going to take them out of the country it is not you, so you would import them, and have to pay tax.

@Willeke of course, as then you'd have imported them with the intent to distribute. Whether you made money from that distribution is irrelevant.

So you're bringing 2 laptops for sale of gifting to others (what happens with them afterwards is utterly irrelevant to the customs officials, or the law).
The total catalog value of those items would count towards your total duty free import amount, and each on their own would almost certainly exceed that amount (and if you're going to be questioned, they may well question your stated purpose for the other 2 as well, especially if they are all the same or similar and look pretty new).
At the very least declare the two you're planning to leave behind (again, that the recipients are planning to take them out of the country a few days later is irrelevant to Dubai authorities), and be ready with solid arguments and being willing and able to prove that you're going to take the others back out. I'm not sure how that'd work in Dubai, but I'm sure Dubai customs will be happy to advise you.
For example some countries (not sure about Dubai) require you to fill out a detailed list of all expensive items (meaning everything over a certain individual value) in your possession upon arrival, and on departure that list is checked against everything in your possession at that time. If something's missing you'd best have a believable story (and "I lost my $1500 laptop when it slipped out of my bag and over a cliff" is unlikely to be believed).

And of course the two friends who are going to bring the laptops to India are supposed to declare them and pay tax on them when they arrive in India. On their actual value, of course, not "it was a gift so it's free".

If Dubai allows for items to be checked upon departure as you describe, theoretically one could pass Dubai customs on exit with laptops still on their belongings, and give it to their friends in the customs-free zone before they all proceed onto their flight. If you need to leave the customs-free zone for any reason (cancelled flight etc), then things get more complicated. This all is of course only really possible if you're taking the same flight, and does not rid your friends of their obligation to declare them in India (and pay any resulting taxes).

@ave of course, and that's the only way to handle this short of sending the laptops to India by courier to be picked up there (which courier would handle declaring them to Indian customs and charge the recipients).
